# Split on comma for a column, and then search other matching values?

Tags: mysql

Wondering if there is an easier way to do this in mysql, rather than looping through a query per row in PHP.  I need for each distinct ID, to get other IDs that have the same category, and then output those as another column, preferably space or comma delimited.  Further enhancement would be to search for multiple categories and join the IDs if the comma separated categories match.

I have a table that looks like this:

```
id    name    category
100   Thing0  Blue
101   Thing1  Red
102   Thing2  Blue,Red
103   Thing3  Blue
```

I need an output like this:

```
id    category    new_col
100   Blue        102 103
101   Red         102
102   Blue,Red    100 101 103
103   Blue        100 102
```

It does not matter if the row in questions id is placed in the new_col.  Any help is much appreciated...

Comment: What is the maximum number of categories per item? (Please don't say "unlimited" unless it truly is unlimited)

Comment: This is complicated enough, and does enough things that are difficult in SQL, that I would probably create a console application to do this.

Comment: No more than 3 categories more than likely.  I figured there was probably some mysql that could be optimized rather than a query of category matches per id, but perhaps its more than a single query can pull off...